# For $a,b \in \Bbb Z$, if $ax+by=2$ for some $x$ and $y$ in $\Bbb Z$, then $(a,b) = 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I understand a counterexample is when $a=4, b=-3$ and $x=y=2$.

Yet, I get confused because according to this Bezout's identity it states that $ax+by=(a,b)$ Therefore shouldn't the above statement be true or am I misunderstanding the identity.

Comment: That is not what Bezout's identity states. It states that there are some $x$ and $y$ satisfying it, not that they all will.

Comment: Bezout's identity states that $(a,b)$ is the _smallest_ positive number of the form $ax+by$ for integers $x,y$. There are of course other linear combinations that reach other numbers.

Comment: An easier counterexample is $a=b=x=y=1$.

Answer (score 3):

$d=(a,b)$ is the smallest natural number for which there exist $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ax+by=d$, but it is not the only natural number that has this property. In fact, all multiples of $d$ will. So if $d=1$, as in your example, then all natural numbers have this property.

Comment: so the above statement is only true when d=1? It does not work for when d=2

Comment: If $d=2$, then all even natural numbers can be written as $ax+by$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Since a,b $\in$ Z, which include negative numbers this statement is not true because it only works for even positive numbers even though it states for some x,y . Correct?

Comment: I don't think it matters whether $a$ and $b$ are positive or not.

Answer (score 0):

$ax+by=c$ only means $c$ is a multiple of $\gcd(a,b)$.